Linking log messages to lines of source code in Goland
While running code in the Goland terminal, if my code panics it logs something like:
panic: 

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        /home/omustardo/go/src/demo/main.go:22 +0x1c5
exit status 2

"/home/omustardo/go/src/demo/main.go:22" is a link which takes me to the exact file and line within the IDE. Awesome!
I confirmed that using fmt.Println with that same string also results in a link. I'd like to use this pattern in a logging library so that all of my logs let me jump right to the relevant code.
I'm currently using glog (https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/golang/glog) which already includes part of the file path:
~/go/src/demo$ go run .
I0919 01:21:14.925218  450629 main.go:19] Hello World!

Unfortunately this alone isn't enough for Goland to add a link. I didn't find any configuration option for this, but it feels like it should be theoretically possible for Goland to figure out file paths purely based on this log message.
If Goland doesn't support it, I thought that if I could find the prefix (in this case "/home/omustardo/go/src/demo/") then I could prepend it to the path and all would be good. Getting the path prefix is harder than I expected though.
One solution is a flag that holds the directory where the program was built from. It's not a bad option, but it does require manually setting this flag. If panic() can get the full path then surely there's a way that's fully automated.
I've tried:

Using reflection to access runtime.defaultGoroot. It seems that there's no way to use reflection to access package variables that are private, or maybe I just missed something.
Digging through Go src for how panic is implemented. I didn't figure it out, but this test seems closely related to how it does stack traces. After a lot of digging, it appears to just use the GOROOT environmental variable, but there must be more to it that I just didn't understand.
replicating the implementation of the unit test linked above, where it executes a subcommand without GOROOT set in order to get a value which is purported to have been set to the build path. It just ended up hanging forever.

I've spent more time on this than I should, and I'll probably go with the flag approach in the end, but if anyone knows how to do this properly I think it would be broadly useful.

The underlying issue here was surprisingly simple. I should have tested more of my basic assumptions. It turns out Goland links to files for both local and relative filepath:line_num combinations! The reason it wasn't working for glog's lines like main.go:19] was simply because of the right bracket. This seems like a clear bug with Goland so I'll file a bug report. (EDIT: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-17484/Jump-to-source-from-terminal-logs-is-broken-but-easily-fixable)
Regarding the other question of how to get the current file path and line number, there are a few good options.
Standard log library
Just let the built in log library handle it for you:
import (
    "log"
)

func main() {
    log.SetFlags(log.LstdFlags | log.Lshortfile)
    log.Println("with file/line")
}

$ go run .
2024/09/19 21:21:09 main.go:9: with file/line

You can use log.Llongfile to log the full path.
runtime.Caller(skip int)
func main() {
    if _, file, line, ok := runtime.Caller(0); ok {
        fmt.Printf("%s:%d\n", file, line)
    }
}

$ go run .
/home/omustardo/go/src/demo/main.go:18

